# SketchUp - Twinmotion Workflow : When to add interior features

Tags: sketchup

I'm currently working on my first SketchUp model of the first floor of a townhouse (going to be coffee shop) and have extruded the 2D floorplan out to 3D. Is there an industry standard for when to add interior and exterior features like windows and doors? That is, what features should be added to the model (SketchUp) and what should be saved to be done in the rendering step (Twinmotion)?

Comment: Which industry uses sketchup for floorplans? Which industrys standard are you looking for? This place is for graphic design there are no standards for sketchup here. Hell outside of using an application that produces a PDF, jpeg or png maybe OTF not many standards in the industry as a whole. But the requirement of each job may have more standards.

Comment: Interior design, possibly architecture - there's not a stackexchange site for either of those (that I found) specifically, and I did see some SketchUp related questions so I thought I'd ask here. The two applications in question are fairly powerful, but I imagine that trying to do something that's better suited for the other will give me headaches only avoidable by experience. I was hoping to find someone with that experience. If I'm off topic, or too general, then so be it. I totally get it if this needs to be locked.